# identify if elements in input list are in other lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, break

I am really new at this and I'm trying to finish this simple program, it's supposed to print a list of products and ask the user to select which ones they would like to get.

If the product they input is in the original lists of products, it should proceed, if it ain't, it should print a message saying its invalid and prompt the user to select again.

Heres a bit of my code

My lists of products:

```
Medicina = ("jarabe", "ampolleta", "capsulas")
Electronica = ("computador", "scanner", "impresora")
Ropa = ("vestido", "pantalon", "blusa")

while True:

    Products = input ("ingrese el nombre de sus productos separados solo por una coma: ").split(",")
    print (Products)
    
    for x in Products:  
        if x in Medicina:
            break
        if x in Electronica:
            break
        if x in Ropa:
            break
        
    print ("ingrese productos validos")
        

print (Products)
```

the problem is, no matter what product I input, it always marks it as an invalid product. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't forget to tag your questions with a language (i.e. Python).

Comment: The `break` is inside the `for` loop and does not break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Do you want it to error if any products are invalid or all products are invalid?

Comment: @JeffUK if any products are invalid. Only if all of them are valid its supposed to break out of the loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How can I make it break out of the while loop?

Comment: @Mischievousmoogle You could do it with `for/else` and `continue`. [Here's an example](https://repl.it/@JohnnyMopp/ImperfectWarmheartedMicroprogramming#main.py). Not posting as an answer because it's not really the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the lists together using addition then use `in` to check them all at the same time.

Additionally, functions work well to 'return a value' and stop running a loop both at the same time.

```
Medicina = ("jarabe", "ampolleta", "capsulas")
Electronica = ("computador", "scanner", "impresora")
Ropa = ("vestido", "pantalon", "blusa")


def invalid_products(Products):

    for product in Products:
        if product not in Medicina + Electronica + Ropa:
            print("Enter valid Product")
            return True
    return False

Products =[]

while(invalid_products(Products) or not Products):
      Products = input ("ingrese el nombre de sus productos separados solo por una coma: ").split(",")
```

Comment: I prefer while loops that say what they're waiting for! not (True) and in reality you would have a 'Categories' list that contains each of your tuples, you should concatenate all categories together dynamically rather than hard-coding it like I have here.

Answer (score -1):

```
Medicina = ("jarabe", "ampolleta", "capsulas")
Electronica = ("computador", "scanner", "impresora")
Ropa = ("vestido", "pantalon", "blusa")

while True:

    Products = input("ingrese el nombre de sus productos separados solo por una coma: ").split(",")
    print(Products)

    if Products in Medicina +Electronica +Ropa:
        break

    else:
        print("ingrese productos validos")
```

Tip: always try using as little as possible for/while loops or if statements and keep your code short and simple doing something like what you did makes your code always run slower and full of bugs

Note: you still can make this shorter and better but I am leaving this as a challenge for you have fun.

2nd Note: I am sorry but I didn't understand the language you are using so I just copied a string and pasted it

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I saw the problem sorry and thanks for pointing it out I am just too tiered that I made the dumbest mistake i could have done

Comment: Yes there is a motivation on SO to get the fastest answer out, but the problem is if it is not correct it will get downvoted quickly and the dv'ers usually don't hang around to undo the dv when the answer gets fixed. (There was talk on meta about dv'ers getting notified when a question is edited. Not sure if that ever became policy because I rarely dv).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp as said I am sorry for posting without double checking I didn't even try to post my answer as fast as possible. I was and still am too tired that  i didn't notice doing some dumb mistake Thanks again for pointing my mistake out.

Answer (score -1):

In the code you used, the line `print ("ingrese productos validos")` prints every time even if you break from the if statement. Use this code instead

```
Medicina = ("jarabe", "ampolleta", "capsulas")
Electronica = ("computador", "scanner", "impresora")
Ropa = ("vestido", "pantalon", "blusa")

while True:

    Products = input ("ingrese el nombre de sus productos separados solo por una coma: ").split(",")
    print (Products)

    for x in Products:
        if (x in Medicina):
            break
        elif x in Electronica:
            break
        elif x in Ropa:
            break
        else:
            print ("ingrese productos validos")

print (Products)
```